# JavaScript Object Manipulation showing identical values for different keys after unique manipulation

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, javascript-objects, key-value

I'm working on a Node.js backend that is pulling different values for the same date keys. I have the code below, in it I declare a months Object that stores the default list of dates (shortened for simplicity).

These values are then assigned to different keys as a template for the final data object to be returned.

I've simulated data manipulation by increasing the numIncrease value by 1. The desired output is:

```
{ '2019-01-01': 6 }
{ '2019-01-01': 7 }
{ '2019-01-01': 8 }
{ '2019-01-01': 9 }
```

But when I run it, I'm getting the code below:

```
data: { key1: { '2019-01-01': 15 },
  key2: { '2019-01-01': 15 },
  key3: { '2019-01-01': 15 },
  key4: { '2019-01-01': 15 } }
```

Also, numIncrease doesn't increase by only 1 each time. Unless I'm missing a blatant scope error, I've heard that there are some "weird" things with the way JavaScript works under the hood. I'm still learning, so this is turning out to be quite the learning experience.

The example below is ready to run. Thanks for your help!

```
let months = {
    '2019-01-01': 5,
}

// key data key is assigned to months for template use
let data = {
    key1: months,
    key2: months,
    key3: months,
    key4: months,
}

// Initial Num Increase
let numIncrease = 1

/**
 * Key 1
 */
for (let date in data.key1) {
    data.key1[date] += numIncrease
}
numIncrease += 1; // increase num to simulate different manipulation on next key
console.log(data.key1) // key1: { '2019-01-01': 6 }

/**
 * Key 2
 */
for (let date in data.key2) {
    data.key2[date] += numIncrease
}
numIncrease += 1; // increase num to simulate different manipulation on next key
console.log(data.key2) // key2: { '2019-01-01': 7 }

/**
 * Key 3
 */
for (let date in data.key3) {
    data.key3[date] += numIncrease
}
numIncrease += 1; // increase num to simulate different manipulation on next key
console.log(data.key3) // key1: { '2019-01-01': 8 }

/**
 * Key 4
 */
for (let date in data.key4) {
    data.key4[date] += numIncrease
}
numIncrease += 1; // increase num to simulate different manipulation on next key
console.log(data.key4) // key4: { '2019-01-01': 9 }

// For some reason all data key nums now equal the last iteration through where key4 = 15
console.log("data: ", data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, there is only one `months` object in memory. All of your keys (key1, key2, key3, and key4) are pointing to this month object. Therefore, as you go through your code, you're manipulating the same month object in memory. In other words, they *must* be identical because there is only one `months` object!

If you want them to be different objects, consider creating a copy when assigning to all your keys. The following example uses the spread operator to do so.

```js
let months = {
    '2019-01-01': 5,
}

// key data key is assigned to months for template use
let data = {
    key1: { ...months },
    key2: { ...months },
    key3: { ...months },
    key4: { ...months }
}

// Initial Num Increase
let numIncrease = 1

/**
 * Key 1
 */
for (let date in data.key1) {
    data.key1[date] += numIncrease
}
numIncrease += 1; // increase num to simulate different manipulation on next key
console.log(data.key1) // key1: { '2019-01-01': 6 }

/**
 * Key 2
 */
for (let date in data.key2) {
    data.key2[date] += numIncrease
}
numIncrease += 1; // increase num to simulate different manipulation on next key
console.log(data.key2) // key2: { '2019-01-01': 7 }

/**
 * Key 3
 */
for (let date in data.key3) {
    data.key3[date] += numIncrease
}
numIncrease += 1; // increase num to simulate different manipulation on next key
console.log(data.key3) // key1: { '2019-01-01': 8 }

/**
 * Key 4
 */
for (let date in data.key4) {
    data.key4[date] += numIncrease
}
numIncrease += 1; // increase num to simulate different manipulation on next key
console.log(data.key4) // key4: { '2019-01-01': 9 }

// For some reason all data key nums now equal the last iteration through where key4 = 15
console.log(data)
```